# Excel: How to generate real random numbers having as low and high 2 real numbers?

Tags: excel, random

How to generate real random numbers having as low and high 2 real numbers?

I want random numbers between: 2.7 and 3.2. What should I write to get this? :) :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
= 2.7 + (3.2-2.7)*RAND()
```

Comment: think it is Rand() rather than Random()